# Получаю NaN при решении формулы

Tags: c#

При решении одной формулы с использованием чисел с запятой, я получаю в ответе NaN
Но при решении той же формулы с целыми числами, ответ получается адекватный

Тут все адекватно

```
for (double x = 1; x <= 10; x ++)
{
    double value = 2 * ((x - 1) / (x + 1)) +
                   (Math.Pow((x - 1), x) / (3 * Math.Pow((x + 1), 3)));
    Console.WriteLine("Для x = " + Math.Round(x, 2) + " Ответ: " + Math.Round(value, 2) + "\n");
}
```

Проблема в этом коде:

```
for (double x = 0.1; x <= 1; x += 0.1)
{

    double value = 2 * ((x - 1) / (x + 1)) +
                   (Math.Pow((x - 1), x) / (3 * Math.Pow((x + 1), 3)));
    Console.WriteLine("Для x = " + Math.Round(x, 2) + " Ответ: " + Math.Round(value, 2) + "\n");

}
```

Comment: В случае отрицательного основания, показатель не может быть дробным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае с дробным `x`, в результате `(x - 1)` в основании степени оказывается отрицательное число. При этом показатель степени является дробным.

Для этого случая есть описание в [справке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netcore-3.1)

```
x < 0 but not NegativeInfinity; y is not an integer, NegativeInfinity, or PositiveInfinity. result = NaN
```

Comment: Возможно ли как то обойти это?

Comment: @loveu, не использовать `Math.Pow` например, плюс, не любое отрицательное число можно возвести в дробную степень.